# How to Bubble sort in C an array of type struct using temporary int (tmp)?

Tags: c

I get error from the compiler because I can't assign an integrer type `tmp` to a struct type. I try to bubble sort array of struct type. The code is bigger than this but I think this is enough to provide all the info you need.

```
struct varor{
     int varunummer;
     char namn[WORDLENGTH];
     int lagersaldo; 
 };
 typedef struct varor Vara;

 void sorteraVaror(Vara reg[]){
         int i,j, tmp;
         for(i=0; i< MAX-1; i++){
             for(j=0; j<MAX-1; j++){
                 if(reg[j].varunummer>reg[j+1].varunummer){
                 tmp=reg[j].varunummer;
                 reg[j].varunummer=reg[j+1].varunummer;
                 reg[j+1].varunummer=tmp;
                 }
             }
         }   
 }
```

Comment: The variable tmp should be of the type Vara. Also this condition if(reg[j]>reg[j+1]){ does not make sense because the operator > is not defined for structure.

Comment: As I understand you have to swap structure objects instead of just one their data member

Answer (score 0):

As @vladfrommoscow points out, and in other words; tmp must be of the same type as the structs in the array.